# Text goes out of alignment when screen size reduces with bootstrap 4 and AngularMaterial2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material2

I have the following HTML code that looks fine when screen size is wide. 
However, when the screen is small, the check box goes out of alignment as shown in the image. 
I want to align the neatly towards the left edge when the screen is small.

If I change md-check box to normal labels the problem is not there so I believe it is the internal styling of the md-checkbox

I have tried adding paddings and margin the md-checkbox and they dont work. What could I try to resolve this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <md-checkbox>Some long Text</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox>Some other longer text</md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: large scren]
[image: small screen]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter class while giving column size

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <form>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Some Text
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">Some Other text
    </label>

  </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey sorry, when I was trialing I actually have col-md-12 which produced the result as shown in the image.

Comment: No still go the issue unfortunatelly. I have updated the question with proper code

Comment: Hey @shyamm, thanks for the update. Setting the type="md-checkbox" does not work. I think I will have to use <md-checkbox>. And that messes with the layout

Comment: in bootstrap4 they  have changed syntax a bit!

Comment: <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1

Comment: try this, it'll work! and plz upvote the answer if u find it useful

Comment: I am using Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/component/checkbox which builds on top of bootstrap 4.I could try and use the original bootstrap method if I exhaust all the options for md-checkbox

Comment: can you plz provide jsfiddle for it??